# Parse command line arguments string into array for posix_spawn/execve

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, posix

Given single string `cmd` representing program command line arguments, how to get array of strings `argv`, that can be passed to `posix_spawn` or `execve`.

Various forms of quoting (and escaping quotes) should be processed appropriately (resulting invocation should be same as in POSIX-compatible shell). Support for other escape characters would be desirable. Examples: [#1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187452/58083), [#2](https://blog.cloud66.com/bash-tricks-part-1-string-escaping/), [#3](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Quoting).

Comment: You tagged your question with both [c++] and [c]. Do you want a solution that is legal in both languages?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you can use `std::string`.  The `std::string` class has a lot of useful parsing methods.  Also, with `std::string`, you don't have worry about memory management of the data.

Comment: I'm fine with using a library that can be used from C code (this includes C++ libraries, as it's straightforward to wrap them for such usage).

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html

Comment: `Given single string cmd representing program command line arguments, how to get array of strings argv, that can be passed to posix_spawn or execve` What have you tried? What research did you do?

Comment: Windows has `CommandLineToArgvW`, in Python there's `shlex.split`. It's unclear how to handle quoting correctly. Proper handling of quoted arguments may be specified in POSIX specification, but I couldn't find that section.

Comment: How much of the shell syntax are you going to handle?  Variable expansions?  Command substitutions?  Process substitutions?  I/O redirection?  Without knowing that, it is hard to suggest how to proceed.

Comment: No variable expansions and no command substitutions. I'd like to support quoting and escape characters properly though. So various (edge) cases shown in following links would ideally work.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187452/58083 -
https://blog.cloud66.com/bash-tricks-part-1-string-escaping/ -
https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Quoting

Comment: @iljau Please update your question to indicate that you desire support for quoting and escape characters.

Comment: Support for full bash syntax is a big ask (bash isn't narrowly POSIX after all). Are you fine with just support for bourne shell syntax, as defined by POSIX? In an earlier comment you said you only wanted quoting and escaping characters.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use [`system()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)? Do you not have the C std lib available? Do you specifically only want the array, but not want to run anything?

Comment: "bourne shell syntax, as defined by POSIX" would be fine.

Comment: I'm using other `posix_spawn` features in addition to executing command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shawn commented, in Linux and other POSIXy systems, you can use [wordexp()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html), which is provided as part of the standard C library on such systems.  For example, run.h:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Execute binary 'bin' with arguments from string 'args';
   'args' must not be NULL or empty.
   Command substitution (`...` or $(...)$) is NOT performed.
   If 'bin' is NULL or empty, the first token in 'args' is used.
   Only returns if fails.  Return value:
     -1: error in execv()/execvp(); see errno.
     -2: out of memory. errno==ENOMEM.
     -3: NULL or empty args.
     -4: args contains a command substitution. errno==EINVAL.
     -5: args has an illegal newline or | & ; < > ( ) { }. errno==EINVAL.
     -6: shell syntax error. errno==EINVAL.
   In all cases, you can use strerror(errno) for a descriptive string.
*/
int run(const char *bin, const char *args);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and compile the following C source to an object file you link into your C or C++ program or library:

```c
#define  _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wordexp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int run(const char *bin, const char *args)
{
    /* Empty or NULL args is an invalid parameter. */
    if (!args || !*args) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -3;
    }

    wordexp_t  w;

    switch (wordexp(args, &w, WRDE_NOCMD)) {
    case 0: break;  /* No error */
    case WRDE_NOSPACE: errno = ENOMEM; return -2; 
    case WRDE_CMDSUB:  errno = EINVAL; return -4;
    case WRDE_BADCHAR: errno = EINVAL; return -5;
    default:           errno = EINVAL; return -6;
    }

    if (w.we_wordc < 1) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -3;
    }

    if (!bin || !*bin)
        bin = w.we_wordv[0];

    if (!bin || !*bin) {
        errno = ENOENT;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Note: w.ve_wordv[w.we_wordc] == NULL, per POSIX. */

    if (strchr(bin, '/'))
        execv(bin, w.we_wordv);
    else
        execvp(bin, w.we_wordv);

    return -1;
}
```

For example, `run(NULL, "ls -laF $HOME");` will list the contents of the current user's home directory.  Environment variables will be expanded.

`run("bash", "sh -c 'date && echo'");` executes `bash`, with `argv[0]=="sh"`, `argv[1]=="-c"`, and `argv[2]=="date && echo"`.  This lets you control what binary will be executed.

Comment: `wordexp()` is not Linux only, it is available in all POSIX systems ([reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html)).

Comment: @ShaneBishop: Very true, good point.  Reworded.  The man page at man7.org [I linked to](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) (`man 3 wordexp`) does mention it in the Conforming to section, and even has a separate POSIX man page for [wordexp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3p.html) (`man 3p wordexp`).

Comment: When you say that command substitution is not performed, that is incorrect. From the `wordexp` link you provided to the Linux man page, it says, "The expansion done consists of the following stages: [...] command substitution."

Comment: @ShaneBishop: No, command substitution is *optional*.  Because the code uses the `WRDE_NOCMD` flag, command substitution is not done.  See the man pages I linked to ([man 3 wordexp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) and [man 3p wordexp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3p.html)).  Another useful flag is `WRDE_UNDEF`, with which wordexp() will fail returning `WRDE_BADVAL` if an undefined shell/environment variable was expanded.

Comment: All that said, I don't use wordexp() for *everything* myself.  For example, if parsing configuration files with internal variables that are not suitable for (or are too many to) adding into the environment, I use a state machine that handles quotes (single and doublequotes), backslash escape sequences (ASCII, hex, and Unicode), and variable expansion, and depending on the domain use case, arithmetic expressions, using one or two simple hash tables of name-value pairs.  (The second for arithmetic functions.)